# Google Apps Scripts, Distance Matrix URL not properly forming

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-apps-script

The overall point of the app is to calculate and display the distance between two addresses defined by html inputs.The problem I am encountering is when the `Calculate` button is clicked it opens a new tab with a weird URL, "https://n-u3xjzi7wklp272w6mwu2e3jc3umixhe6rym5h7i-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel?origin=&destination=" which I'm guessing is actually supposed to be the distance matrix request url since the weird URL includes `origin=&destination=` but I definitely could be wrong.

Here is my Current Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Distance Between two Addresses</h2>
<form id="distance_form">
    <label>Origin: </label>
    <input id="origin" type="text" name="origin"/>
    <br/>
    <label>Destination: </label>
    <input id="destination" type="text" name="destination"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate"/>
</form>
<div id="result">
</div>
  </body>

  <script>

$(function () {

  function calculateDistance(origin, destination) {
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
  }

  function callback(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      $('#result').html(err);
    } else {
      var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
      var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
      if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        $('#result').html("Better get on a plane. There are no roads between " 
                          + origin + " and " + destination);
      } else {
        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
        var distance_value = distance.value;
        var distance_text = distance.text;
        var miles = distance_text.substring(0, distance_text.length - 3);
        $('#result').html("It is " + miles + " miles from " + origin + " to " + destination);
      }
    }
  }

  $('#distance_form').submit(function(){

      var origin = $('#origin').val();
      var destination = $('#destination').val();
      var distance_text = calculateDistance(origin, destination);
  });

});

  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAxmrFQipNODQwlv57BHQxati2jR8_xWdA" async defer></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour on a form submission is to open a new page, which is what causes the strange URL in an Apps Script web app. You can turn this off by adding the following into the  of your HTML:

```
<script>

  function preventFormSubmit() {

    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form')

    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {      
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
      })
    }

  } // preventFormSubmit()

  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit)

</script>
```